# asyncio.TimeoutError from None Error while using ClientSession

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm currently using `aiohttp` and `asyncio` libraries to send multiple POST requests asynchronously to a single endpoint. My steps were to create chunks of 30k requests at a time and gather the responses into a dictionary and write them into files.

Following is the exception that I'm getting:

> INFO -   File
> "/export/home/daiusr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py",
> line 656, in **exit** [2021-10-11 13:32:11,356] {bash_operator.py:157}
> INFO -     raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None [2021-10-11
> 13:32:11,356] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -
> concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError

Please find my methods:

```
def extract_data(self):

    # sf_values_dict_items is a dictionary with the values for post request body
    # the chunk_dict method creates a single batch of 30k requests out of entire 35 mill odd records
    for chunk in chunk_dict(sf_values_dict.items(), records_and_response_limit):
        self.propagate_log_msg('processing batch of {} responses'.format(records_and_response_limit))
        asyncio.run(concurr_req(self, chunk))

@staticmethod
async def concurr_req(self, sf_values_dict):
    global global_val_list
    global_val_list = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        list_values = []
        for v in sf_values_dict.values():
            list_values.append(json.dumps(v))

        newlist = [json.loads(l) for l in list_values]

        tasks = []
        # making async calls to get the response
        for i in newlist:
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_responses(self, session, i)))

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

@staticmethod
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      (aiohttp.ClientResponseError, aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError, aiohttp.ClientOSError),
                      max_tries=10)
async def get_responses(self, session, data):
    global global_val_list
    global global_failed_val_list

    async with session.post(self.url,
                            data=json.dumps(data),
                            headers=json.loads(self.headers_t),
                            raise_for_status=True) as resp:
        try:
            if resp.status in [200]:
                global_val_list.append(await resp.json())

        except Exception as e:
            self.propagate_log_msg('Exception occurred after max retries: {}'.format(str(e)))
            global_failed_val_list.append(data)
            
    return resp
```

The exception is raised in the highlighted line (in yellow) below:

[image]

followed by this line:

> await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

Please let me know if I'm missing anything, or if anyone has come across this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know in case if I need to append more info into the question.

**NOTE: The entire 35 mill odd requests which I'm trying using the above snippet gets completed in a 10 hr airflow job. But at times it fails due to this timeout error which I can't figure out why**

Comment: If your fine with couple requests failing, adding `return_exceptions=True` in the `gather()` call might be one option.

When you send 35 mil requests, I think a couple of them timing out is not a very rare occurrence.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, sure I can try that and see. I'm anyways capturing the failed requests to process them later so yeah that should be fine.